# Duvida para rotina em Pascal

Tags: pascal

Preciso escrever uma rotina que faça um calculo em que é informado um valor e aplicado um percentual. Ambos, o valor e o percentual devem ser solicitados. Realizar este cálculo através de uma function, retornando o valor final com o percentual aplicado.

Comment: Quando tiver [dúvidas específicas de programação](/help/on-topic) procure explicar sempre o que tentou e qual foi a dificuldade enfrentada. Aqui tem umas dicas para melhor aproveitamento do site: [Ask], [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/70) e [Help].

Answer (score 1):

Suponho que o seguinte código resolva teu problema.

```pascal
function calcPorcentagem(valor, porcentagem: integer): double;
var
   valorParcial: double;

begin
     // Calcula o valor percentual
    valorParcial := ((valor * porcentagem) / 100);

    // Soma ao valor inicial a porcentagem desejada
    calcPorcentagem := (valorParcial + valor);
end;
```